# If I use 1099 or S-Corp, can I deduct rent from my income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, self-employment, eligible-expenses

If I live in another state in USA and either still pay rent or mortgage, but rent an apartment in Silicon Valley and work there to earn money as a business (1099 or S-Corp), then can't I deduct that rent from my income for taxes?

Or what if I lived in another country and either still pay rent or mortgage over there, and come to Silicon Valley and rent an apartment, then can't I deduct that rent from my income?

It sounds logical that if I do this as a business, then the rent should be deductible. Say, if the rent is $3000 or $4000, vs if I can get a Motel 6 room for $80 / day and I rent it for $2400 per month, then the $2400 is deductible?

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to deduct **some** of it.  However, it is limited to the portion of the apartment that is used exclusively for work.

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/home-office-deduction

Comment: I would highlight "exclusively" as well as it is a critical distinction. For example - you can't deduct the bedroom as a business expense just because it's in an_area_ where you work.

Comment: so what if I just live in a motel? Then it is 100% deductible? What if it is Airbnb?

Comment: It is great that you are trying to plan ahead.  Would you be using the motel exclusively for work or would you be using it for other purposes? I suggest you work with a tax professional and read the link I shared from the IRS website.